# How to resolve missing css file during ng build?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I recently upgraded my Angular version from 8 to 10. After fixing all the issues that came up and installing updated versions of all components, I am still facing one final issue during `ng build`.

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '@fullcalendar/core/main.css'
  in [
    D:\Source\Repos\Vims\VIMS\VIMS-App\src
  ]
    at D:\Source\Repos\Vims\VIMS\VIMS-App\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

I have tried updating packages, un-installing and re-installing @fullcalendar/core along with `ng prune`, but the error just won't go away. I am still missing main.css in the folder.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried /src/styles.css instead of ./src/styles.css in angular.json?

Comment: @Puriajahanbani : angular.json is fine. The issue is that main.css is missing from the folder.

Comment: can you check if fullcalendar is there in devDependencies of package.json, if its not there please add it and do "npm i" again

Answer (score 7):

As stated in update notes for fullcalendar you should remove references in your style.css to the fullcalendar *.css files as with the updated version they are not longer needed. Every plugin will take care for it's own styling.

> In v4, it was your responsibility to import all of fullcalendar’s
> stylesheets. You may have done this in one your project’s SASS files.
> Or, if you had a build system that handled CSS, you may have done this
> from your JavaScript.
>
> In v5, you no longer need to do this! The plugins will import their
> own stylesheets (with the exception of the bootstrap plugin).

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4

Comment: Tried commenting and the terminal fail error disappeared but created a new error only seen inside browser console as, "Uncaught Error: Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin."

Comment: @LeslieNyahwa Please import fullcalendar lib, before any plugin, as said in error. For example:
import { Calendar, EventClickArg } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by copying main.css from @fullcalender/common/ to @fullcalendar/core/

Answer (score 0):

My project is aprox 7mb. I guess that angular compiler while using aot and prod switches strips out some css code. So I turned on vendor chunks to true in tsconfig. And it works. Try that maybe it will solve your problem.